# What is the name of the quaternion-like group generated by rotations and multiplications?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, quaternions

I know that the algebra of quaternions is isomorphic to the division algebra of 2×2 complex matrices which are real multiples of the elements of SU(2). I also know that SU(2) is a double cover of SO(3).

The scalar multiples of the elements of SO(3) also form a group (or even an algebra?). Is there a name for this group (or algebra)?

Answer (score 0):

The clearest name is just "rotation-dilation group". Using, as suggested, the name "conformal group" will only work if explicitly restricted to **linear** conformal transformations, otherwise one might immediately think of the Möbius group, which does include rotations and dilations but also other transformations.